# Align UItextFields one below the other in interface builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton, uitextfield, uibuttonbaritem

How to align 2 textfields one below the other in a tool bar and display a button on the left side (or right side) in the vertical middle of those two fields? Please see the image to know what I am talking about.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/art/ui_textfields.jpg

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that's a toolbar?

It looks like a UIView with a background, that's added on top of the map view. You can create a UIView, adjust two text fields and a button to look like that in Interface Builder.